# LaTeX Math Mode in algorithmic environment

Tags: math-mode, algorithmicx

The following code works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State \Call{MergeSort}{$T(1,\dotsc,n)$}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

However, if I replace `$...$` with `\(...\)`, I get an error for some reason. So the following code does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State \Call{MergeSort}{\(T(1,\dotsc,n)\)}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

I thought `$...$` and `\(...\)` are equivalent. Why can this be happening? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\Call` macro uses `\ifthenelse`, which has a very handy feature: it allows combining tests with propositional logic connectives (called `\AND` and `\OR`) with parentheses for the stating the precedence. Here's the catch! The symbols for these parentheses are `\(` and `\)`. So the presence of `\(` and `\)` in the second argument of `\Call` (that is used in an `\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}` test during processing if `\Call`) confuses TeX, because at the time of this evaluation `\(` and `\)` *aren't* the math formulas delimiters, but rather the “propositional logic parentheses”.

So, use `$`.

Alternative solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode,amsmath,xifthen}

\algrenewcommand\Call[2]{\textproc{#1}\ifthenelse{\isempty{#2}}{}{(#2)}}%

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State \Call{MergeSort}{\(T(1,\dotsc,n)\)}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

This works because `xifthen` introduces a new `\isempty` test that doesn't interpret its argument. Of course also other `algpseudocode` macros would need similar treatment.

Comment: seems that the `\( ... \)` conflict should be mentioned in the `algpseudocode` documentation (`algorithmicx` bundle).  doesn't seem to be, so maybe someone could report it to the author.